# Making Mac shortcuts (e.g. Cmd-C) work on linux

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to map **<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** to Copy in linux? (instead of **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**)

Would be nice if I could also have the emacs style ones, like **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>** to move left by one character.

Comment: Best to mention whether you are using gnome/kde/somethingelse as shortcut settings usually are best set from the top down.

Comment: @chris I really like the question out of personal interest (Mac at home, Arch with xfce4 at work). I have to agree with wds though. The desktop environment is really important to mention (nice list here to choose from): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way, on Linux/X, to map certain key combos to other key combos?

In the tradition of all open source projects, there's not *a* way, there are *several*.  At the lowest level you've got kernel keybindings, which is probably not what you want.  At the X server level you've got xkb with its myriad utilities.  And then it seems that every window manager - gnome, kde, xfce or other - also has a keymapping utility.   xkb seems to have lots of utils and such around it, and is likely more complete than any random window manager's keymapping utils, so I'd look at that first.

Answer (score 6):

KDE 3 is probably the most flexible here; there's a pre-defined keyboard shortcut scheme named "Mac Scheme".  You can set it through KControl `Control Center > Regional & Accessibility > Keyboard Shortcuts` or `kcmshell keys` and it will have effect on almost all KDE applications immediately.  You might miss some of those Emacs-like "Ctrl-*" shortcuts that OS X has, but that aside, it works well (as long as your X modifiers are mapped correctly).  And if it's not to your liking, it's easily customizable.

You can also set `Control Center > Desktop > Behavior` to enable a Mac OS-like menubar; all KDE applications will then share a menubar at the top of the screen instead of being individually attached to each window.

Comment: Agreed - I've managed to get Konqueror and Konsole to behave much like Safari and Terminal, which makes me happy.  I can even use alt-shift-Q to log out.

Answer (score 6):

**Update 02/03/2020**

Kinto has now been rewritten in C for Ubuntu/Debian systems using x11. It also uses json config files, making it easier to manage and extend to other applications than just terminals. The app no longer maps to Super in the Terminal apps, it will now properly map to Ctrl+Shift to create the exact same feel as having a Cmd key.

Please checkout the latest release.
https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

The main change to allow for the Super = Ctrl+Shift change is in this symbols file.

```
default partial xkb_symbols "mac_levelssym" {
    key <LWIN> {
      repeat= no,
      type= "ONE_LEVEL",
      symbols[Group1]= [ Hyper_L ],
      actions[group1]=[ SetMods(modifiers=Shift+Control) ]
    };
    key <RWIN> {
      repeat= no,
      type= "ONE_LEVEL",
      symbols[Group1]= [ Hyper_R ],
      actions[group1]=[ SetMods(modifiers=Shift+Control) ]
    };
};
```

---

Pjz's answer is correct in saying that an xkb solution would be ideal, sadly few have taken that route, most likely due to the difficulty of learning xkb and it seems many have gone the route of using Xmodmap files which is being deprecated while we are on our way to Wayland.

This answer may be several years too late, but here it is any ways.

Kinto is a tool I recently created that will address this problem and does so by using xkb and by listening to what app you are currently using, as it also changes the keymap while using terminals so the mac like experience can be consistent.

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

https://medium.com/@benreaves/kinto-a-mac-inspired-keyboard-mapping-for-linux-58f731817c0

Here's a Gist as well, if you just want to see what is at the heart of it all, it will not alternate your keymap when needed though. The Gist also does not include custom xkb keymap files that setup macOS style cursors/word-wise manipulations that use Cmd and the arrow keys.

https://gist.github.com/rbreaves/f4cf8a991eaeea893999964f5e83eebb

Edit: Posting the contents of the gist as well. I cannot realistically post the contents of Kinto.

```
# permanent apple keyboard keyswap
echo "options hid_apple swap_opt_cmd=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
update-initramfs -u -k all

# Temporary & instant apple keyboard keyswap
echo '1' | sudo tee -a /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/swap_opt_cmd

# Windows and Mac keyboards - GUI (Physical Alt is Ctrl, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Super)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win

# Windows and Mac keyboards - Terminal Apps (Physical Alt is Super, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Ctrl)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win

#
# If you want a systemd service and bash script to help toggle between
# GUI and Terminal applications then look at project Kinto.
# https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto
#
# Note: The above may not work for Chromebooks running Linux, please look
# at project Kinto for that.
#
# If anyone would like to contribute to the project then please do!
#
```

Comment: True, I often get annoyed when a link breaks, at the same time it also isn't very realistic to attach an answer that is several files, and hundred or thousands of lines long.

I suppose I could have posted the contents of the gist however, as it is the answer that boils down what Kinto does, by providing a real answer even though it cannot change keymaps on the fly.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because although it's a fine answer, the question itself is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It was fine in 2009, but 10 years later, there are Stack Exchange sites specifically for this type of general computing question.  Ideally, this question should be **closed**.

Comment: I was not aware of this being the case, but it is understandable. I suppose Stackoverflow is now geared more towards actual coding questions and answers, not system level modifications and scripts that can be categorized into the other exchanges, which I do participate in and answer as well.

I am a web developer myself, and may get into doing some kernel development soon, but I have not contributed much to this or any other exchange until recently.

Comment: @RBenR I think you improved your answer a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get almost all of the way there if you switch Cmd and Ctrl

Answer (score -1):

xmodmap -e "keycode 63 = Control_L"

That way Cmd will be Control. No other keys will be swapped

Edited: I forgot the "-e"